# Powershell AD script unable to export to csv

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I wrote a code and have a problem to export it to csv.
So the code is comparing the list of AD users to a Distribution Groups or number of Distribution Groups and it works perfectly. I only cannot export it to .csv.

```
Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $true} -SearchBase "OU=Location" |% { $_.samAccountName } | out-file "C:\users.txt"
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Company" |% { $_.samAccountName } | out-file "C:\Members.txt"

$List = Get-Content ("C:\Members.txt")
$ListOfUsers = Get-Content ("C:\users.txt")

$compare = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $ListOfUsers -DifferenceObject $List -IncludeEqual 
foreach($Inp in $compare)
{
$notice = $Inp.InputObject 
    If ($Inp.SideIndicator -eq "==")
    {

        "$notice User is avaiable in Distribution List"
    }
    elseIf ($Inp.SideIndicator -eq "<=")  
    {
        "$notice User is not available in Distribution List "
    } 
}
```

If I add at the end of the line export-csv it giving me something like this:

[image]

My question is:
how to export it correctly to receive InputObject as a Name, SideIndicator as a Notice and Comparison Operators as information if the user is inside the Distribution Group or not?

Comment: Could you clarify your question with perhaps an example of your desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we keep your current logic, you can achieve the desired results with calculated properties in [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7).

```
$compare = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $ListOfUsers -DifferenceObject $List -IncludeEqual
$hash = @{'==' = "{0} User is available in distribution list" -f $compare.inputobject
          '<=' = "{0} User is not available in distribution list" -f $compare.inputobject
}
$compare | Select-Object @{n='User';e={$_.InputObject}},@{n='Notice';e={$hash.($_.SideIndicator)}} |
    Export-Csv output.csv -NoType
```

**Explanation:**

The calculated property, which is a hash table with specific key-value pairs, allows you to output a custom property name along with a corresponding custom value. It requires having a key that represents the name of the property and a key that is an expression for your value. The name can be represented as `l`,`n`,`name`, or `label`. The value expression can be `e` or `expression`.

Creating the `$hash` hash table is merely to make the calculated property more readable. It simply has a key that matches your desired `SideIndicator` values so that we can dynamically return the message you require.

You can change the property names `User` and `Notice` to whatever you wish.